# Formik React with 2 buttons (Submit and Save) to submit form - Save button not to trigger validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

Pretty new with Formik, I have a simple form, which has validation. I need to have 2 buttons, Submit and a Save button which will mostly do the same thing, however, if "Save" button is clicked, I want the validation to be "disabled" or rather, all required fields will no longer be required. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Some codes below:

```
const initialValues = {
    title: "",
    description: ""
};

const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        title: Yup.string()
            .max(50, 'You may only enter up to 50 characters')
            .required('Required'),
        description: Yup.string()
            .max(200, 'You may only enter up to 200 characters')
            .required('Required'),
        })


const CreateForm = () => {

    const handleCancel = () => {
        alert("Cancelled!")
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Formik initialValues={initialValues}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}
                onSubmit={(values) => {
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                    }, 3000)
                }}
            >
                {props => (
                    <Form>
                        <CustomTextInput label="Title"
                            name="title" type="input" placeholder="Enter Title" />

                        <CustomTextInput label="Description"
                            name="description" type="input" placeholder="Description" />

                        <div>
                            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
                                Submit
                            </Button> &nbsp;
                            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="secondary" >
                                Save
                            </Button>&nbsp;
                            <Button variant="contained" color="default" onClick={handleCancel}>
                                Cancel
                            </Button>
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CreateForm
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly remove `type="submit"`. Because `formik` will understand it like submit and will validate it. Second add `onClick` function:

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  color="secondary"
  onClick={() => handleSave(props.values)} >Save</Button>
```

And:

```
const handleSave = (values) => {
  // do what you want like on submit
}
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't realize it was that simple. Thank you so much!

Comment: How would I do the same except I have to validate only a few fields in case of save and all fields in case of submit, how would I do that?

Comment: @SirajAlam I found [this on github](https://github.com/formium/formik/issues/467#issuecomment-369833667), shouldn't that solve it?

Comment: problem with this: you might get invalid values, whereas formik won't call `onSubmit` with invalid form values.

Comment: Most browsers default button elements to `type="submit"`. Add `type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you need to have a `submitButtonState` and check the value of this state when submitting the form.

```
const [submitButtonState, setSubmitButtonState] = useState(null)

const handleSubmitButtonState = (isSubmit) => {
  setSubmitButtonState(isSubmit)
}

//...
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    //...
  }}
  onSubmit={(values) => {
 // check submitButtonState value here
  console.log(submitButtonState)
  }}
  >
  {() => (
  <Form>
  //...
    <section>
      <button type="submit"
      onClick={() => handleSubmitButtonState("skip")}
      >
      Skip for now
      </button>
      <button
        type="submit"
        onClick={() => handleSubmitButtonState("submit")}
      >
      Submit
      </button>
     </section>
    </Form>
   )}
 </Formik>
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a variable

```
  const [btnClicked, setBtnClicked] = React.useState('');
```

Add the onMouseOver event to buttons setting a value

```
        <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                 <Button type="submit" onMouseOver={(event)=>{
                   setBtnClicked('save');
              }}> Save </Button>

              <Button type="submit" onMouseOver={(event)=>{
                  setBtnClicked('save_and_close');
              }}>Save and close </Button>
        </form>
```

On the formik submit event you can get the value of the button selected to do whatever you want

```
      const formik = useFormik({ 
         initialValues: { },
         validationSchema: yup.object({ }),
         onSubmit: (values) => {
            if(btnClicked == "save"){
              // option 1
            } else {
              // Option 2
            }
         }
       });
```

Comment: Very large chance the event triggers before the rerender updates the state. I'd stay away from this solution.

Comment: setstate will take time and meanwhile, onSubmit will trigger with stale state